# Python prepend to regex match

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, replace

I am writing a python program that will need to be able to mirror content on another site.

After downloading the html, I need to replace all of the relative links (eg. `<img src='/foo.png'>`) with complete links (eg. `<img src='http://thesitewherethepageisfrom.com/foo.png'>`).

I also need to replace all the relative file paths. For instance if I downloaded `http://example.com/bar/foo.php` and it has `<img src='foobar.jpg'>` I actually need to replace that with `<img src='http://example.com/bar/foobar.jpg'>` and not `<img src='http://example.com/foobar.jpg'>`.

I am currently using the regexes:

```
((?<=src=[\"'])|(?<=href=.))(?!(http(s|)(:|%3[Aa])))[0-9A-Za-z%?&#_=+.~]([0-9A-Za-z%?&#_=+./~])*(?=['\"])
```

and

```
((?<=src=[\"'])|(?<=href=.))(?!(http(s|)(:|%3[Aa])))([0-9A-Za-z%?&#_=+./~])*(?=['\"])
```

for relative and full file paths that are not a complete link. Does python provide a way to prepend text to every regex math? I need to be able to iterate through the matches and prepend `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/bar/` to each of them.

Comment: You mean `re.sub()` perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes but I would need to be able to know the match I was substituting for so i didn't just replace it with `http://example.com`

Comment: You can use a *function* as the replacement and it'll be passed in the `MatchObject` for each match.

Comment: You should probably look at `lxml` which can handle parsing HTML properly - more specifically http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html which has functions designed for re-writing links

Answer (score 0):

Prepending some text to a regex match in `re.sub` is possible with the help of the [`\g<0>` backreference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

In your case, the substitution pattern for the `re.sub` method will look like `r'http://example.com/bar/\g<0>'`.

In a general case, you need to remember that a backslash is a special char in `re.sub` replacement patterns. To actually replace with a single backslash, you will need to double it. So, the general solution will look like

```py
import re
text = r"<img src='foobar.jpg'>"
my_regex_pattern = r"""((?<=src=["'])|(?<=href=.))(?!(http(s|)(:|%3[Aa])))([0-9A-Za-z%?&#_=+./~])*(?=['"])"""
prefix = r"http://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/bar/"
res = re.sub(my_regex_pattern, prefix.replace('\\', '\\\\') + r'\g<0>', text)
print(res)
# => <img src='http://example.com/bar/foobar.jpg'>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wSsviZ/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/a8RpF2).